# XML bitmaps doesn't render well?

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm using a PNG pattern to fill some backgrounds in my app, but it is not rendering so well as it should. I created the pattern in Photoshop and use it for many things and it works just fine, but with the same image i can't get the same results in Android. Check this:

- Photoshop image:

  [image]
- Android image:

  [image]

This is the XML I use to create the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item>
       <color 
           android:color="@color/dark" />
   </item>
   <item>
       <bitmap 
           android:src="@drawable/bg_stripes_dark_image"
           android:antialias="true"
           android:dither="true"
           android:tileMode="repeat" />
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Same pattern, same size, but different results. Am I missing something or it is really an Android's problem rendering repeated images?

Comment: putting the image in `drawable-nodpi` directory should solve the problem

Comment: It looks like your image is being scaled up automatically. In which drawable resource folder do you keep the pattern image?

Comment: @vmironov It worked, i was putting the image in `drawable` folder instead. Can you build an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is getting automatically upscaled by android. The simplest workaround is to put the image in `drawable-nodpi` direcory.